# AI tools for generating clean clipping paths

Tags: image-processing, photoshop, photoshop-script, clipping

how to generate clean clipping paths. I've tried using Photoshop's automatic feature, but it often produces inaccurate or messy results. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries, or other off-site resources are off-topic here. This is what happens when you don't take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting. Doing so will greatly improve your experiences here going forward.